# How to resolve error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on IIS server?

Tags: c#, iis

I got the ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED after deploy on the iis server and connect to the website to its hostname. However the site still connect when I use IP. Specially, the hostname is still useable and not expired. How can I check what's wrong with it?

Comment: What result do you get when you run `nslookup www.yoursite.ext` at the command line?

Comment: It show:
Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find  ... : non-existent domain

Comment: I have just edited my comment. It shows: non-existent domain

Comment: Ok so your domain is either misspelled or *if* spelled correctly, then it is not registered globally. If it's a local domain (e.g. `my.testsite.local`) then put it in your `hosts`-file, pointing to the right IP address.

Comment: Ok so what is the host file name and where I can find on the server?

Comment: It's on the **client**. See here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: Sounds like your site bindings are not right. Run a report with Jexus Manager to get more info, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: Does it work with windows server?

Comment: I deploy it on a server computer through remote desktop connection. The server use windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise. I have tried the Jexus Manager but its connection was failed